# How to make both req.files and req.body available in nodejs when the api is sent with axios

Tags: node.js, post, request, axios

I'm using Axios npm package in my Node.js application which is a built-in microservices architecture. API-gateway is using Axios to call other services.

According to axios documentation, for POST method, request format is like: axios#post(url[, data[, config]]) . means only one argument data.

Can anyone tell me how I can send req.body & req.files data separately to Axios?

Comment: so you want to send both files and json data? so that you can access files with req.files and access json with req.body?

Answer (score 0):

According to [answer](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1006#issuecomment-320165427) in Axios community to familiar question this could be achieved with the npm package [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data), which simulates WebAPI FormData on the node side.

This would allow you to send files and form fields to the API and receive it in form of multipart form data.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const form = new FormData();
// Second argument  can take Buffer or Stream (lazily read during the request) too.
// Third argument is filename if you want to simulate a file upload. Otherwise omit.
form.append('field', 'a,b,c', 'blah.csv');

axios.post('http://example.org/endpoint', form, {
  headers: form.getHeaders(),
})
.then(result => {
  // Handle result…
  console.log(result.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundle your data up as an object, and pass that object through to the axios request as a single payload.

On the other side of the API, you can access the object, and do as you wish.

`var payload = { property1: 'values', property2: 'values2' }`

now you pass payload around